# I have written an anagrams finder that has a double for loop - how do I increase the efficiency of this code?

Tags: java, string

In response to the Hackerank problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-making-anagrams/problem where one must find the number, as an integer, of characters to be removed from a string to make it an anagram of another string.

I have completed the code and the program passes the tests but I am wanting help with increasing its efficiency. How do I go about thinking how to improve the efficiency of the following code?

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Hackerank {

    // Complete the makeAnagram function below.
    static int makeAnagram(String a, String b) {
        int letterToRemoveCount = 0;
        Set<Character> characterMapA = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Character> characterMapB = new HashSet<>();

        for(int i = 0; i< a.length(); i++) {

            if (!characterMapA.contains(a.charAt(i))) {
                characterMapA.add(a.charAt(i));
                if ((countOccurences(a.charAt(i), a) - countOccurences(a.charAt(i), b)) != 0) {
                    letterToRemoveCount += Math.abs((countOccurences(a.charAt(i), a) - countOccurences(a.charAt(i), b)));
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j<b.length(); j++){
            if (!characterMapB.contains(b.charAt(j)) && !characterMapA.contains(b.charAt(j))) {
                characterMapB.add(b.charAt(j));
                if ((countOccurences(b.charAt(j), a) - countOccurences(b.charAt(j), b)) != 0) {
                    letterToRemoveCount += Math.abs((countOccurences(b.charAt(j), a) - countOccurences(b.charAt(j), b)));
                }
            }
        }
        return letterToRemoveCount;

    }

    public static int countOccurences(char m, String s){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++){
            if(s.charAt(i) == m){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(makeAnagram("fcrxzwscanmligyxyvym", "jxwtrhvujlmrpdoqbisbwhmgpmeoke"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer, but you might try this. Create an array of 26 ints. Convert the characters to their ascii values and shift the values so the range is 0-25. Increment the cells of the array based on the chars in the first string, decrement based on the second. Then parse the array and add up the absolute values. This is also linear running time, but has fewer linear steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rule of optimization: Avoid unnecessary operations:

- Like calling to `contains` before calling `add`.

Second rule of optimization: If you want it faster, you'd better lean on memory:

- Do not call the same function several times with the same input values: Better call only once, store the value in a local variable, and use it afterwards.
- Also, computing the number of occurrences of a character in a string is not efficient (the longer the strings, the least efficient): Better create a map for each string, mapping each character to a number of occurrences.
- Dave's suggestion about how to optimize such maps is interesting, too.